# Unable to send Email to Lead from Sales Cloud due to AMPScript error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, leads, marketing-cloud-connect, email-studio

We are trying to send email to a Lead from Sales Cloud, but our sends are getting failed. I believe the error is due to the AMPScript, but not sure what is the reason its failing. Can someone help on this one.

```ampscript
%%[ 
var @email, @lookup, @CaseRow, @Name, @EmailID 
Set @email = AttributeValue("Email") 
Set @lookup = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead", "First Name, Email", "Email", "=", @email) 
Set @CaseRow = Row(@lookup, 1) 
Set @Name = FIELD(@CaseRow, "First Name") 
Set @EmailID = FIELD(@CaseRow, "Email") 
]%%
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I see a double quote is missing in the lookup function for the first name

Comment: There's no missing double-quote, but maybe an extra space: https://ampscript.guide/RetrieveSalesforceObjects/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend defensively checking your [**rowcount**](https://ampscript.guide/rowcount) before attempting to pull values from the results.  Also, I try to use the `emailaddr` [**system string**](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings) if I need the email address.  It's safer to use in an email send context.

```ampscript
%%[ 

var @email, @lookup, @CaseRow, @Name, @EmailID 
Set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr") 
Set @lookup = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead", "First Name,Email", "Email", "=", @email) 

if rowcount(@lookup) > 0 then
  Set @CaseRow = Row(@lookup, 1) 
  Set @Name = FIELD(@CaseRow, "First Name") 
  Set @EmailID = FIELD(@CaseRow, "Email") 
else
  Set @Name = "Valued Customer"
  Set @EmailID = @email
endif

]%%
```

Comment: Hi Adam, its not displaying the First Name by using the Code you shared above, We also tried by removing the extra space between but still no luck.

Comment: Does "First Name" match what you see in Synchronized Data Extensions for Lead for that property?

Comment: Thanks Adam, It worked after I added the field in the Lead Data Source in Synchronized Data Extensions

Comment: @LijoJohns, that's bizarre as sync DE's is not a requirement to use the function. Also, 'First Name' should definitely be 'FirstName' (which is the API name of the standard field). On a related note, I would discourage using RetrieveSalesforceObjects in an email as it's very slow. Instead, sync the object and use AMPscript to lookup the Sync DE. I had one client that used RetrieveSalesforceObjects in an email and sent to 1m Leads, we calculated it would take 1.5 years for the send to finish as it was sending <300 per hour!

Comment: Thanks Eliot, I will be using Sync DE and using AMPSCRIPT as I have to send email to a larger audience.